# Suppose the joint pdf of  and  answer the following questions:

Tags: statistics

[image]

How can I answer the questions with these information

Comment: X and Y are not independent.  For example if X=30, Y must =0.  Statement has f(x).  Shouldn't it be f(x,y)?

Comment: Yes it should be f(x,y)

Answer (score 1):

Analytic geometry is the way to approach this problem.  The area of interest is a trapezoid $T$ with bounds positive $x$ axis, positive $y$ axis, and lines $x+y=20$ and $x+y=30$.  The first step is to calculate $k$ so that $\int_Tf(x,y)dxdy=1$.  To get $P(X+Y\le 25)$, draw line $x+y=25$ and integrate $f(x,y)$ over that part of $T$ to the left of that line.

$E(X+Y)=\int_T(x+y)f(x,y)dxdy=m$.  To get $V(X+Y)$, get second moment $M= \int_T(x+y)^2f(x,y)dxdy$ and $V(X+Y)=M-m^2$

For the last two, you need $E(XY)$, $E(X^k)$ and $E(Y^k)$ for $k=1$ and $k=2$ calculated the same way as other expectations.  Standard formulas apply.